# Factorize a number in C

Tags: c

I want do a program of factorization like this: 72 = 3 * 2 ^ 3 ^ 2

in C language, how can i do the program ?

**I tried to do this but I can not do it :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int n;
int j;

printf("Insert a positive integer number greater than 1\n")
scanf("%d", &n);
j = 2;
do
{
  if( n % j == 0)
  {
     printf("%d\n", j);
     n = n / j;
  }

  else{
     j++;
     }
}

while ( n > 1);
}
```

Comment: "but I can not do it :"  --> What was your input, output seen and expected/desired output?

Comment: From your description `72 = 3 * 2 ^ 3 ^ 2`, it's not clear what sort of factorization you want.  Your program outputs `2 2 2 3 3` for the input 72. Is the problem that it does not express `2 2 2` as `2^3`?

Comment: I think you mean `72 = 2^3 * 3^2`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that given 72, you want to output `2^3 X 3^2` this code should do it:

```
/* Decides when to print multiplication sign */
const char *get_mult_string()
{
    static int first_divisor=1;

    if (first_divisor==1) {
        first_divisor=0;
        return "";
    } else {
        return " X ";
    }

}

void factorize() {
    int n;
    int j;

    printf("Insert a positive integer number greater than 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    j = 2;
    int power_count=0;

    do {
        if (n % j == 0) {
            power_count++;
            n = n / j;
        }

        else {
            if (power_count>0) {
                printf("%s(%d^%d)", get_mult_string(), j, power_count);
                power_count=0;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    while (n > 1);
    if (power_count>0) {
        printf("%s(%d^%d)\n", get_mult_string(), j, power_count);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array, where each slot represents a prime number, and initialize them all to 0. For example, array[0] means 2, array[1] 3, array[2] 5, array[3] 7, array[4] 11.

Rather than printing out the prime number when you reach it, as you do in your code, increment that slot in the array. In the end, you can call something like `printf("2^%d * 3^%d * 5^%d * 7^%d * 11^%d",array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4])`.

Note: switch statements would probably be your friend here.